# excel minimize, restore button action vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel document and I am trying to use it for visualization. I have a VBA to hide, sheet tab, formula bar, tool bar, menu bar. it works when I open the document freshly. When I minimize or restore the document, the menu and toolbars show up automatically. I would like to keep them hidden all the time.

Comment: What do you do to hide it now?

Comment: You have to run those commands based on the [workbook open event](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm)